# belongsTo() not returning relationships for User

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I already tried several things but I can't get this to work. I want to be able to make something like this `{{ $user->city->name }}`

My user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['id_city', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}
```

And this is my City model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'cities';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use `{{ $user->city->name }}` on my view but it doesn't work, it returns an error **ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: .../views/app/text.blade.php).**

What should I do?

Comment: Is `user` of class `User`?  Is `city` meant to be a call to the function of that name?  Then it needs ()'s.  How about giving us [mcve]?  Then we won't have to keep asking questions to figure out what's going on; we can see it for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship, Eloquent tries to match `city_id` as the foreign key by default as you don't pass the second argument.

However, according to your fillable attributes, what you have as the foreign key is actually `id_city`.

For the User model,

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'id_city');
}
```

For the City model,

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id_city', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for! Just made those changes and it works perfectly.